# javascript search function not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, function

Hey All I have this javascript function that actively searches a table I have on my web page. The function working in Mozilla and Chrome but not in IE. Can anyone help me tweak this so it will work in all browsers? here is the code:

```
function playerSearch(phrase, _name){
    var words = phrase.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var table = document.getElementsByName(_name)[0];
    var ele;
    for (var r = 1; r < table.rows.length; r++){
       ele = table.rows[r].innerHTML.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,"");
        var displayStyle = 'none';
        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (ele.toLowerCase().indexOf(words[i])>=0)
                displayStyle = '';
            else {
                displayStyle = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        table.rows[r].style.display = displayStyle;
    }
}
```

Here is the function call from the html page: 
    `<span id="filter" class="filter">Player Search:<input onkeyup="playerSearch(this, 'currentTable')" type="text"></span>`

Comment: Can a variable begin with an underscore?

Comment: The whole function, when I enter a phrase in the search box in IE nothing happens, but in chrome and moz it filters the table displaying only things containing the phrase string

Comment: In what way are you calling the function, you're not giving enough details to help. We can't get it through osmosis

Comment: Without the associated HTML, it's hard to debug.  You should create a jsfiddle/jsbin entry.

Comment: Is "ele" short for "elephant"? because I always find elephants can cause some strange bugs in code ;)

Comment: sorry, here is the function call from the html page:
`<span id="filter" class="filter">Player Search:<input  onkeyup="playerSearch(this, 'currentTable')" type="text"></span>`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like IE is insisting on inserting a tBody dom element. try altering `var table = document.getElementsByName(_name)[0];` to `var table = document.getElementsByName(_name)[0].tBodies[0];`

**EDIT**

After reading the comments below and doing a bit of googling it turns out that `name` is not a global attribute and not a valid attribute on tables according to the [HTML4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) (this is unchanged in the current draft of the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#tabular-data))  this is unfortunatly one of the times when IEs javascript engine is being a stickler for the rules returning an array of 0 length when you do `document.getElementsByName(_name)` , and the other browser manufacturers are actually breaking the specification.

Comment: still not working, would it have something to do with the innerHTML call? IE doesn't like that too much right? Is there a way to execute that line with jquery syntax?

Comment: @user1258430 You are right. You can't set `innerHTML` for `<TR>`-element. Attempting to do so causes "Unknown runtime error".

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the feedback after doing abit more research it turns out IEs javascript engine is strictly enforcing the HTML specification which states that name is not a valid attribute on a table element and so wont return any tables on the initial javascript query. updated my answer with more information.

Comment: any work around recommended? Is it possible to do it with jquery syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer which works in all browsers. Separate function are given for IE, NetScape and all other browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    var OtherBrowser = (document.getElementById);
    var IE4 = (document.all);
    var NS4 = (document.layers);  
    var win = window;
    var n = 0;


    function findInPage(str) {
        var txt, i, found;
        if (str == "") {
            alert("Enter some thing to search");
            return false;
        }

        else if (IE4) {

            txt = win.document.body.createTextRange();

            for (i = 0; i <= n && (found = txt.findText(str)) != false; i++) {
                txt.moveStart("character", 1);
                txt.moveEnd("textedit");
            }
            if (found) {
                txt.moveStart("character", -1);
                txt.findText(str);
                txt.select();
                txt.scrollIntoView();
                n++;
            }
            else {
                if (n > 0) {
                    n = 0;

                    findInPage(str);
                }
                else
                    alert("Sorry, we couldn't find.Try again");
            }
        }
        else if (OtherBrowser) {
            if (!win.find(str)) {
                while (win.find(str, false, true, false, false, false, true))
                    n++;
            }
            else if (win.find(str)) {

                n++;
            }
        }


        if (NS4) {
            if (!win.find(str)) {
                while (win.find(str, false, true, false, false, false, true))
                    n++;
            }
            else if (win.find(str)) {
                n++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save yourself some trouble while applying some slick table functionality (including filters, which I *think* you're trying to achieve here), I suggest DataTables.

http://datatables.net/